# problem using facebook connect module

Tags: 7, users

i installed the module Fbconnect in my drupal 7 site

the fbconnect button starts appearing now but the window which opens upon clicking the button, gives the error ,"An error occured, try again later."

Anyone please help

Comment: Set "php_flag display_errors on" into your main .htaccess to know about error crashing the site.

Comment: thaks brother. i have almost solved these problems but fbconnect button is not shown on the site.. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have put in the api key, I think you are missing that. Have you also enabled it on certain node types you want to display.

Comment: i have put the application id and app secret. How to enable where to display?

Comment: even the button starts appearing now but the window opens gives the error "An error occured, try again later."

Comment: timeout error or page not found error?

Comment: simply an error occured try again later

Comment: Any update on this? I am experiencing the same problem.